# MVC3 Razor conditional loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, combobox, razor

I want to implement following:
A combobox/DropDownListFor named "target" in a view. It contains (e.g.) A and B as choice.
In the same view I have another combobox named "medium". Its content depends on the chosen target, e.g.: 
- if target = "A", combobox "medium" will show 1 and 2 as choice.
- if target = "B", combobox "medium" will show 3 and 4 as choice.

I have implemented combobox "target" successfully, but I don't know how to implement combobox "medium" related to "target". If I am not wrong, the logic should be: get the chosen targetid -> find all medium related to the targetid -> fill combobox "medium" with the result.

Here is snippet of my current view (combobox "target"):

```
<div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TargetId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TargetId, (ViewData["targets"] as SelectList).MakeSelection(Model.TargetId))
</div>
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: You'll need to use either ajax to reload the medium combobox or javascript to dynamically change the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the javascript OnChange of the first drop to do an ajax call to obtain the values based from the choice A or B.

Then with the JSon response you get from the controller you fill the dropdown "Medium"

in the JS file do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#target").change(function () { GetMediumValues("#target", "#medium"); });
});

function ClearDrop(objSource) {
   $(objSource).empty();
}

function GetMediumValues(objSource, objDest) {
var url = '/mySite/GetMediumValues/';
$.getJSON(url, { id: $(objSource).val() }, function (data) {
    ClearDrop(objDest);
    $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
        $(objDest).append("<option value='" + optionData.Value + "'>" + optionData.Text + "</option>");
    });
});
```

}

While in the controller

```
public ActionResult GetMediumValues(string id)
{
  int myId = 0;
  int.TryParse(id, out myId);
  var select = new SelectList(repository.GetMediumValues(myId), "Id", "Name");
  return Json(select, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //allow get needed to allow get calls 
}
```

Comment: Thx. I still have 2 questions. Q1: in JS what does var url mean? I run my webclient on localhost. So I need to set url to /localhost/GetMediumValues/ is that correct? Q2: how can I implement combobox "medium" now?

Comment: Q1: the url is from the root of your mapped site. So remove localhost. You can use also absolute url like www.mysite.com/getvalues

Comment: Q2: Simply output your dropdown with an empty selectlist. or already populated if the first drop is binded with a value. You do that from your controller when you prepare your viewmodel imo